# Getting text within h3 tag using Mootools Element properties

Tags: mootools

I have the following mootools code, please note that I need to get a cetain value in mootools and have no good mootools knowledge

I have the following html code

```
<div class="moduletable_menu">
    <div class="tog">
        <h3>Main Menu</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">

        <ul class="menu">.....</ul>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="moduletable_menu">
    <div class="tog">
        <h3>Newsletter</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
//Newsletter form
        </div>
</div>
```

I have the following mootools code

```
var modules = $$('.cont');
var toggles = $$('.tog');

modules.each( function(mod, index){
             //I need to get the innerHTML for h3 in here 

});
```

This loops through all div tags that contain the class "cont", I however need to obtain the inner HTML for the h3 tag within div tag with class "tog", by looping through the div tags with the cont class?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getPrevious` will help you get the toggle div given a module div, and `getElement` will get the h3 element within it.

See an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/NPABY/).

```
modules.each(function(module) {
    var toggle = module.getPrevious('div.tog');
    var headingText = toggle.getElement('h3').get('text');
});
```

Comment: can you paste a link to where you are seeing this error? see the working example in my answer.

Comment: Never mind  var headingText = tog.getElement('h3').innerHTML; worked, thanx for pointing me in the right direction, I'll accept your answer

Comment: he already has the 2 collections in memory. you can optimise this not to do module.getPrevious() and just use `var h3text = toggles[index].getElement("h3").getText(); // 1.12 getText` in his original `modules.each` loop - http://jsfiddle.net/uVnCu/